# Android Drawer Layout with main activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

was trying the drawer layout example mentioned in [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout)

After trying this out, I added a few elements, like a button, to the main layout. This is what I did :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="openTestButtonActivity"
        android:text="@string/testing" />

     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            .
            .
            .
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the drawer works good, but I am not able to activate my button. Is there anything in the ordering of layouts that I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, layout order is wrong. In relativeLayout views are ordered like are added in code. So if you add button first and then you add drawerLayout, drawerLayout overlays button. So you should add DrawerLayout first and then Button.